# pyschools-tictactoe

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

In the pencil-and-paper game, Tic-tac-toe, 2 players take turns to mark 'X' and 'O' on a board of 3x3 squares. The player who succeeds in marking 3 successive 'X' or 'O' in vertical, horizontal or diagonal stripe wins the game. Write a function that determines the outcome of a tic-tac-toe game.

Examples

```
>>> tictactoe([('X', ' ', 'O'), 
               (' ', 'O', 'O'), 
               ('X', 'X', 'X') ])
"'X' wins (horizontal)."
>>> tictactoe([('X', 'O', 'X'), 
...            ('O', 'X', 'O'), 
...            ('O', 'X', 'O') ])
'Draw.'
>>> tictactoe([('X', 'O', 'O'), 
...            ('X', 'O', ' '), 
...            ('O', 'X', ' ') ])
"'O' wins (diagonal)."
>>> tictactoe([('X', 'O', 'X'), 
...            ('O', 'O', 'X'), 
...            ('O', 'X', 'X') ])
"'X' wins (vertical)."




def tictactoe(moves):
for r in range(len(moves)):
    for c in range(len(moves[r])):      
        if moves[0][c]==moves[1][c]==moves[2][c]:
            a="'%s' wins (%s)."%((moves[0][c]),'vertical')
        elif moves[r][0]==moves[r][1]==moves[r][2]:
            a="'%s' wins (%s)."%((moves[r][0]),'horizontal')
        elif moves[0][0]==moves[1][1]==moves[2][2]:
            a="'%s' wins (%s)."%((moves[0][0]),'diagonal')
        elif moves[0][2]==moves[1][1]==moves[2][0]:
            a="'%s' wins (%s)."%((moves[0][2]),'diagonal')
        else:
            a='Draw.'
print(a)
```

I wrote a code like this and my range is not working(i think). because, it takes the value for r and c as 3, not 0,1,2,3. So, please anyone can help me with this ?
Thank you

Comment: What is the error?

Also, your indentation is wrong.  the for needs to be indented further than def

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop doesn't exit when a player wins. I'd try something like this:

```
def tictactoe_state(moves):
  for r in range(len(moves)):
    for c in range(len(moves[r])):
      if moves[0][c] == moves[1][c] == moves[2][c]:
        return "'%s' wins (%s)." % (moves[0][c], 'vertical')
      elif moves[r][0] == moves[r][1] == moves[r][2]:
        return "'%s' wins (%s)." % (moves[r][0], 'horizontal')
      elif moves[0][0] == moves[1][1] == moves[2][2]:
        return "'%s' wins (%s)." % (moves[0][0], 'diagonal')
      elif moves[0][2] == moves[1][1] == moves[2][0]:
        return "'%s' wins (%s)." % (moves[0][2], 'diagonal')

  # You still have to make sure the game isn't a draw.
  # To do that, see if there are any blank squares.

  return 'Still playing'
```

Also, I'd move the `if` statements that check the diagonals out of the loop. They don't depend on `r` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
def tictactoe(moves):
    for r in range(len(moves)):
        for c in range(len(moves[r])):      
            if moves[0][c]==moves[1][c]==moves[2][c]:
                return "\'%s\' wins (%s)." % ((moves[0][c]),'vertical')
            elif moves[r][0]==moves[r][1]==moves[r][2]:
                return "\'%s\' wins (%s)."%((moves[r][0]),'horizontal')
            elif moves[0][0]==moves[1][1]==moves[2][2]:
                return "\'%s\' wins (%s)."%((moves[0][0]),'diagonal')
            elif moves[0][2]==moves[1][1]==moves[2][0]:
                return "\'%s\' wins (%s)."%((moves[0][2]),'diagonal')
    return 'Draw.'
```

Comment: Please explain why this works.  This prevents copying and pasting without full understanding.